# Is it standard practice create an instance of a class within that class?

Tags: java, class, instantiation

I've come across some code in class Foo with method doSomething() which creates an instance of class foo.

```
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething() {
         Foo foo1 = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Is this standard practice? It seems like a very odd way of going about things. Why would you want to do something like this. Are there dangers of creating code in this way? Is there a reason you would want to do this instead of using some other practice? And finally, my intuition is that any method that did this sort of thing should be declared static. Is that correct?

Comment: IMHO it's not, and is very rare (unless the method is static).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is standard practice. It's not **common** (in an instance method, more common in `static`s), but it's perfectly standard.

The code being in `Foo` is largely irrelevant: If the code needs a `Foo` instance other than `this` for some reason, then it's perfectly normal to create an instance and use it.

It's not really any more odd than a method that creates two instances of a different class:

```
class Foo {
    void method() {
        Bar b1 = new Bar();
        Bar b2 = new Bar();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Presumably, `method` needs both `Bar` instances. Similarly, `doSomething` apparently needs a `Foo` other than `this`.

One place you particularly see this is immutable objects with fluent interfaces, where most methods return an instance of the object with some aspect changed.

```
public class Thingy {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Thingy(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Thingy withA(int newA) {
        return new Thingy(newA, this.b);
    }

    public Thingy withB(int newB) {
        return new Thingy(this.a, newB);
    }

    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return this.b;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Usually the `withX` methods are more interesting than that, but you get the idea... `String` is an example of this, as [5tingr4y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7476069/5tingr4y) points out: `toUpperCase`, `substring`, ...

Comment: @JornVernee: LOL - I thought of immutability the second after posting and was adding it, see above. :-)

Comment: or RecursiveTask:)

Comment: Strings would be a good example of this. trim() and subString(...) and stuff return new Strings.

Comment: In this particular case, the method does not return an instance of the class, but rather a string. It creates a brand new (cloned) instance of itself and then starts a new thread with that instance. Is there a reason to make this new thread with a new instance rather than do all of this work from outside the class?

Comment: @bendl: It doesn't matter what the method returns (see my `Foo` example with two `Bar`s, neither of which is returned). Whether it makes sense in the specific case you're looking at is impossible to say without seeing it (it's too late now to add it to the question, it would make the question a moving target). Clearly the author thought so. Often that means there's a good reason. Not always. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's OK. A good example is a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), which (usually) creates child nodes within the parent node to grow:

```
class Node {
    Node left, right;
    int value;
    Node (int i) {
        value = i;
    }
    void add(int i) {
      if (i < value)
        left = new Node(i); // must create Nodes within Nodes
      else
        right = new Node(i); // must create Nodes within Nodes
}
```